# How could a negative number of entries be omitted?

Tags: r, networking

I am trying to set vertex attributes for a large bipartite network, but I get
`[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted -119353135 entries ]`. How could it be possible to omit a negative number of entries?

Comment: integer overflow somewhere ... ?